# Iphone image paging

Tags: iphone, paging, scroll

I would like to create a photo paging/scroll control.  The control will display three images with which the user can horizontally scroll left and right.

The centre image needs to appear in the foreground with the other two (left and right) appearing to be in the background. So, to achieve this, the centre image will need to scale up as it enters centre position and then scale down as it leaves centre position.

Sort of like a carousel.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really code it for you.
But doesn't seems to be too difficult.

Just change the image size proportional to the distance between the image center and the screen center.

I suggest you use a timer so it won't slow down the phone and start the timer to track the distance (Image center / Screen center) when you start moving the scroll (use delegates method to know when) And stop it when scrolling is down